# Different relation by condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the table **followers**, with:

```
id, user_id, follower_id, type
```

> type = type of follow, if follow user = 0, page = 1, group = 1
>
> I use the **user_id** to put the **page_id** and **group_id** too.

Now is the problem, I want to make different relations if type is different... If type = 0, will relate with users table and share table, if type = 1, will relate with pages table...

I'm try like this:

Model:

```
public function page_links()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Link::class, 'page_id', 'user_id')->Select('links.id', 'links.title', 'links.photo', 'links.country', 'links.friendly_url', 'links.clicks', 'links.description', 'links.suggestions', 'links.count_comments', 'links.url', 'links.shares', 'links.page_id', 'links.tag_id', 'links.created_at')->where('sponsored', 0)->where('scheduled', 0)>where('status', 1)->take(3)->orderBy('id','desc');
}

public function user_links()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Share::class, 'user_id', 'user_id')->Select('id', 'link_id', 'user_id', 'shared_in', 'content', 'created_at')->take(3)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('type', '=', 0);
}

     public function scopeProfile($query) {
        return $query
        ->when($this->type == 0, function($q){
        return $q->with('user_links');
        })
        ->when($this->type == 1, function($q){
        return $q->with('page_links');
        })
        ->when($this->type == 2, function($q){
        return $q->with('group_links');
        });
     }
```

Controller:

```
 $feed = Feed::Profile()->where('follower_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->take(10)
                ->get();
```

But ALL, even the type 1 returns "user_links" relation. I don't know if the relation is correct...

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my point of view, you should modify your migration.

Instead of have your table with :

```
id, user_id, follower_id, type
```

I'll do this :

```
id, user_id, page_id, group_id, follower_id, type
```

Don't do weird stuffs like that in your database, just add 2 fields and / or relations in your migration table. Set it to unsigned() AND nullable(), this way you'll be able to know quickly if there is a relation or not with each one of your page or group, and you won't have to make weird stuff to check for it :D